# Data duplication on post delete (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Every time when I try to delete post (firebase real time database), I get also duplicated posts - simply new posts without previously deleted post are added after old posts. I just cant figure out why and how to fix that. Do you have any idea?

This is my code for post listing from the Firebase real time database (componentDidMount):

```
const postsRef = firebase.database().ref("posts");
    const posts = [];
    postsRef.on("value", snapshot => {
      const originalPosts = snapshot.val();
      for (let post in originalPosts) {
        posts.push({
          id: post,
          tags: originalPosts[post].tags,
          title: originalPosts[post].title,
          source: originalPosts[post].source,
          category: originalPosts[post].category,
          publishDate: originalPosts[post].publishDate,
          author: originalPosts[post].author
        });
      }
      this.setState({
        posts
      });
    });
```

And this is my code for post delete:

```
handleDeletePost = id => {
    const postRef = firebase.database().ref(`/posts/${id}`);
    postRef.remove();
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED.

[React State Storing & Outputting Duplicate Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206722/react-state-storing-outputting-duplicate-values)

> you defined const quests = [] outside of the db change handler. This means that on the second change, you will push everything in the snapshot to the same quests array that may have already had previous snapshots added to it.

Many thanks to Ryan Cogswell